# Elpa + Melpa Certificate information issue at startup

Tags: package-repositories, start-up, gnutls, security

I hadn't used Emacs for a few weeks and when I started it up I discovered issues with certificate information for elpa, melpa and orgmode. When I launch Emacs I get the following message:

The TLS connection to elpa.gnu.org:433 is insecure for the following reasons:

- certificate has expired
- certificate could not be verified

When I look at the details the certificate issuer is Let's Encrypt. I read that the [root certificate for Let's Encrypt expired](https://techcrunch.com/2021/09/21/lets-encrypt-root-expiry/) in September and I wonder if that's the issue? This problem wasn't happening the last time I started up Emacs at the beginning of September.

The trouble is, I don't know how to circumvent this. I've installed OpenSSL and tried to point gnutls-trustfiles to the certificate file in that to see if it helps but that hasn't changed anything. I'm on Windows (Emacs 27.2) and it's difficult to find resources on this.

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

- If on Windows, change `package-gnupghome-dir` to use /c/ instead of c:/
- Run gpg to get the new public key (if on Windows, *in MingW64 shell*)

`$ gpg --homedir /c/Users/micha/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg --receive-keys 066DAFCB81E42C40`

`gpg: /c/Users/micha/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created`

`gpg: key 066DAFCB81E42C40: public key "GNU ELPA Signing Agent (2019) <elpasign@elpa.gnu.org>" imported`

```
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

Note: you may have to delete the `gnupg` directory to get gpg to pull the key again.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to first identify what emacs sees as valid path expression by doing a `Meta`-`!` `pwd`. This revealed on my system that - at least this part of emacs - uses the Cygwin paths (I have it installed since the beginning, much earlier than the problems with ELPA, so don't ask me why that turned into a problem suddenly) like `/cygdrive/c/emacs/bin`. Switching `package-gnupghome-dir` to the respective loacation (`/cygdrive/c/.../.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg`) solved the issue for me. It seems the key there was still valid as I didn't need to refresh it.

*EDIT*
Sadly, this did not solve the issue, it is just that emacs now no longer complains at startup but only when actually accessing the servers with `package-list-packages`.